# SQL Query not returning a value/new row when count = 0; I'd like it to return the 0

Tags: mysql, sql, count, case-when

I'm trying to build a very simple query to return a count of registrations for certain criteria. The database doesn't include a table with exactly what I need, so I'm using a bunch of CASE WHEN's. However, when there are 0 registrations for a certain CASE WHEN statement, the query doesn't return a row and I'd like it to show that 0. Example:

QUERY:

```
select
    (case
when f_id BETWEEN 5700 AND 5718 THEN 'Group A'
when f_id BETWEEN 5719 AND 5736 THEN 'Group B'
when f_id BETWEEN 5531 AND 5544 THEN 'Group C'
else 'Other'
end) as 'Title1',
count(s_id)
from table;
```

RESULT:

```
|Title1|count(s_id)|
|------|-----------|
|Group A|5|
|Group C|2|
```

I want there to be a row for Group B that shows 0 in the count(s_id) column. I've tried IFNULL around the CASE WHEN and also IFNULL(count(s_id),0), and the query either errs or returns the same table above.

I know this is very simplistic but I'm still pretty new to SQL, so any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want all groups, use a `left join`.  I would suggest:

```
select coalesce(title, 'Other') as title, count(t.s_id)
from (select 5700 as lo, 5718 as hi, 'Group A' as title union all
      select 5719 as lo, 5736 as hi, 'Group B' as title union all
      select 5531 as lo, 5444 as hi, 'Group AC' as title union all
     ) g left join
     table t
     on t.f_id between g.lo and g.hi
group by title;
```